# Help with a program that needs to read a data file and output scores

Tags: java, datareader

So I am working on this program (obviously homework):

*In a diving competition, each contestant's score is calculated by dropping the lowest and highest scores
and then adding the remaining scores. Write a program that reads the provided data file formatted as
depicted in the following table. For each diver output the diver's name and total score using the above
scoring rules. Format each diver's total score to two decimal places. So for example, the output for
Chen Ruolin below would be: Chen Ruolin – 56.90 points.*

**Data File:**

```
Chen Ruolin          9.2   9.3   9     9.9   9.5   9.5   9.6   9.8     
Emilie Heymans       9.2   9.2   9     9.9   9.5   9.5   9.7   9.6     
Wang Xin             9.2   9.2   9.1   9.9   9.5   9.6   9.4   9.8     
Paola Espinosa       9.2   9.3   9.2   9     9.5   9.3   9.6   9.8     
Tatiana Ortiz        9.2   9.3   9     9.4   9.1   9.5   9.6   9.8     
Melissa Wu           9.2   9.3   9.3   9.7   9.2   9.2   9.6   9.8     
Marie-Eve Marleau    9.2   9.2   9.2   9.9   9.5   9.2   9.3   9.8     
Tonia Couch          9.2   9     9.1   9.5   9.2   9.3   9.4   9.6     
Laura Wilkinson      9.7   9.1   9.3   9.4   9.5   9.4   9.6   9.2
```

**Diver Class:**

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Diver
{
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Vector scores;

public Diver()
{
    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
    scores = new Vector();
}

public Diver(String firstName, String lastName, double... scores)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.scores = new Vector();

    for (double score : scores)
    {
        this.scores.add( score );
    }
}

public String getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName)
{
    this.lastName = lastName;
}



public String toString()
{
    return firstName + " " + lastName + scores.toString();
}
}
```

**Diver Test Program:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class TestDiver
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("diving_data.txt"));
        scanner.useLocale(Locale.US);

        double[] scores = new double[8];

        while (scanner.hasNext())
        {
            String firstName = scanner.next();
            String lastName  = scanner.next();

            System.out.println("Diver: " + firstName + " " + lastName + " " + scores);

            double min = Double.MIN_VALUE;
            double max = Double.MAX_VALUE;


            for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
            {
                scores[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
            }

            Diver diver = new Diver(firstName, lastName, scores);
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Problem: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

I am by no means a programmer and my head hurts from looking at the code.  My question is this:  How do I get it to read the scores properly.  The names are output fine, but the scores are basically a string of garbled characters.  What am I missing that is causing this problem?

Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You were reading scores, you were just not printing them.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class TestDiver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("diving_data.txt"));
            scanner.useLocale(Locale.US);

            double[] scores = new double[8];

            while (scanner.hasNext())
            {
                String firstName = scanner.next();
                String lastName  = scanner.next();

                // scores is not defined here yet
                System.out.println("Diver: " + firstName + " " + lastName);

                double min = Double.MIN_VALUE;
                double max = Double.MAX_VALUE;


                for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
                {
                    scores[i] = scanner.nextDouble();

                    // prints scores
                    System.out.println(" " + scores[i]);
                }

                Diver diver = new Diver(firstName, lastName, scores);
            }
            scanner.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Problem: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Your program also, just reads the first record of the file, I will leave up to you to modify this code to read all the records.

Comment: I am not sure I follow.  It prints out all of the scores properly now, but it doesn't read all of them?  I take it that because of it only reading the first record, I wouldn't be able to add the scores as per individual diver?

Comment: You have to do a loop to read all of the scores per driver. You also have to add up the individual scores to get a total score.