# For loop trouble in Diving Competition Java Program

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Here is the assignment word for word:
*In a diving competition, each contestant's score is calculated by dropping the lowest and highest scores and then adding the remaining scores. Write a program that reads the provided data file formatted as depicted in the following table. For each diver output the diver's name and total score using the above scoring rules. Format each diver's total score to two decimal places. So for example, the output for Chen Ruolin below would be: Chen Ruolin – 56.90 points.*
*Your program must read the data in from the provided data file and use arrays to store that data. Once all the data has been read in the program needs to calculate each diver's total points and output that diver's name and total points. Where total points is calculated based on the scoring rule defined above.*

So far, I have a program that reads the .txt file and outputs the diver's name and the list of scores. For the life of me I can't figure out how to print just the total score (of course sans the highest and lowest scores). Any help would be greatly appreciated, this assignment is giving me a headache!

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Diver
{
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Vector scores;

public Diver()
{
    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
    scores = new Vector();
}

public Diver(String firstName, String lastName, double... scores)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.scores = new Vector();

    for (double score : scores)
    {
        this.scores.add( score );
    }
}

public String getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName)
{
    this.lastName = lastName;
}



public String toString()
{
    return firstName + " " + lastName + scores.toString();
}
}
```

The TestDiver program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class TestDiver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("diving_data.txt"));
            scanner.useLocale(Locale.US);

            double[] scores = new double[8];

            while (scanner.hasNext())
            {
                String firstName = scanner.next();
                String lastName  = scanner.next();

                System.out.println("Diver: " + firstName + " " + lastName);

                double min = Double.MIN_VALUE;
                double max = Double.MAX_VALUE;


                for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
                {
                    scores[i] = scanner.nextDouble();

                    System.out.println(" " + scores[i]);
                }

                Diver diver = new Diver(firstName, lastName, scores);
            }
            scanner.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Problem: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The .txt file: 
Chen Ruolin     9.2 9.3 9   9.9 9.5 9.5 9.6 9.8
Emilie Heymans  9.2 9.2 9   9.9 9.5 9.5 9.7 9.6
Wang Xin        9.2 9.2 9.1 9.9 9.5 9.6 9.4 9.8
Paola Espinosa  9.2 9.3 9.2 9   9.5 9.3 9.6 9.8
Tatiana Ortiz   9.2 9.3 9   9.4 9.1 9.5 9.6 9.8
Melissa Wu      9.2 9.3 9.3 9.7 9.2 9.2 9.6 9.8
Marie-Eve Marleau   9.2 9.2 9.2 9.9 9.5 9.2 9.3 9.8
Tonia Couch     9.2 9   9.1 9.5 9.2 9.3 9.4 9.6
Laura Wilkinson 9.7 9.1 9.3 9.4 9.5 9.4 9.6 9.2

Comment: Here's a helpful hint:  you're not doing anything with the `Diver` instance you create in your loop; it's just getting left behind.  Each `Diver` has a(n untyped) `Vector` in it, which may help you get the overall total score for that specific diver.

Comment: @Makota is there any chance you could show me how to do that?

Comment: [Looks like your professor reuses assessments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038143/help-with-a-program-that-needs-to-read-a-data-file-and-output-scores)

Comment: @DavidWallace He sure does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the calculation of scores operates only on properties of the `Diver` class, it should be a method of the `Diver` class, rather than being external to the class.  The only logic that your `main` method should contain is the input and output of the data, including the formatting.  So move the calculation logic into the `Diver` class.

Also, if you store the scores in a sorted data structure such as a `TreeSet`, then you don't need any special logic to figure out which scores are the highest and lowest.  All you need to do is iterate through the scores in sorted order and add them up - omitting of course the first and last scores.  This will ultimately make your code more readable.

All your `Diver` class needs then, is the following.  The `Diver` is initially created with no scores, and then scores are added to it.  This saves you from having to cache data in your `main` method.

Notice how I've used a counter, as I increment through the `Set` adding up scores.  I don't add anything to the sum if we're looking at the first element (`counter == 0`) or the last element (`counter == scores.size() - 1`).

```
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Diver {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private SortedSet<Double> scores;

    public Diver(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName  = lastName;
        scores = new TreeSet<>();
    }

    public void addScore(double score) {
        scores.add(score);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public double getFinalScore() {
        if (scores.size() < 3) {
            return 0.0;
        }
        else {
            double sum = 0.0;
            int counter = 0;
            for(double score : scores) {
                if (counter != 0 && counter != scores.size() - 1) {
                    sum += score;
                }
                counter++;
            }
            return sum;
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to, you could include these methods for finding the lowest and highest score, although the assignment doesn't actually ask  you to.  See how easy it is, when you use the classes that the JDK provides for you, instead of trying to write your own logic!

```
    public double getLowestScore() {
        return scores.first();
    }

    public double getHighestScore() {
        return scores.last();
    }
```

Lastly, the test class.  This has the input, output and formatting.  Also, the assignment asks you to store all the `Diver` objects as you read the input file, then output them once you've finished reading the file.  The easiest structure to do this with is an `ArrayList`, because you can keep on adding more objects to it, without having to know how many objects there are to start with.  Most importantly, there is no calculation logic in the test class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestDiver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner("diving_data.txt");
        List<Diver> divers = new ArrayList<>();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String firstName = in.next();
            String lastName  = in.next();

            Diver diver = new Diver(firstName, lastName);
            while(in.hasNextDouble()) {
                diver.addScore(in.nextDouble());
            }
            divers.add(diver);
        }
        in.close();

        for (Diver eachDiver : divers) {
            System.out.format(
                    "%s %s - %.2f points%n", 
                    eachDiver.getFirstName(), 
                    eachDiver.getLastName(), 
                    eachDiver.getFinalScore());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would track the minimum, maximum and the sum of all scores, then do something like:

```
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String firstName = scanner.next();
        String lastName = scanner.next();

        System.out.println("Diver: " + firstName + " " + lastName);

        double min = 11d; //initialize the min value to a high value
        double max = 0d; //initialize the max value with a low value
        double total = 0d; //sum all scores
        double finalScore = 0d;

        for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            scores[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
            if(scores[i] > max) { //if scores[i] > max, we have found a new max score
                max = scores[i];
            }
            if(scores[i] < min) { //if scores[i] < min, we have found a new min score
                min = scores[i];
            }
            total += scores[i]; //sum of all scores
            System.out.println(" " + scores[i]);
        }
        finalScore = total - max - min; //final score, sum of all scores minus min and max
        Diver diver = new Diver(firstName, lastName, finalScore, scores);
        System.out.println(diver.getFinalScoreFormatted());// final score with two decimal places
    }
```

Create a variable in Divers class to hold the final score, then have a getter method to print it with the specified format.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Diver {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Vector scores;
    private double finalScore;

    public Diver() {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        finalScore = 0;
        scores = new Vector();
    }

    public Diver(String firstName, String lastName, double finalScore, double... scores) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.scores = new Vector();
        this.finalScore = finalScore;

        for (double score : scores) {
            this.scores.add(score);
        }
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName + scores.toString();
    }
    // getter method, method that returns the value of the instance variable finalScore
    public double getFinalScore() {
        return finalScore;
    }
    // getter method that returns the final score with two decimal places
    public String getFinalScoreFormatted() {
        DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
        return f.format(this.finalScore);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for this helpful code? Could you please show me what you mean by getter method and also how you would do this? I'm very confused.

Comment: I updated the post to include the changes. If you have any questions please don't doubt to ask them.

Comment: This is a fairly good answer, but it doesn't quite meet the requirements of the assignment.  The assignment asks you to read in all the `Diver` data from the file; and only print it out once it has all been read.  I assume this is to teach the student about what data structure can be used to store this kind of data.  However, that's not quite what you're doing here - you're not storing `Diver` objects at all.

Answer (score 0):

change `scores.length` to a common variable. because scores.length in this code `scores.length`returns 0

Within loop find MAX and MIN.

```
if(scores[i]>MAX){
  MAX=scores[i];
}
if(scores[i]<MIN){
  MIN=scores[i];
}
```

Then pass `MAX+MIN`to diver class and subtract `MAX+MIN`it will be the total score.